# Trouble resolving dependencies involving MaybeT with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am getting back into Haskell and I haven't worked with cabal much.  I am trying to install `maybet`.  When I try to install it, I run into the following error:

```
>>mkaravan$ cabal install maybet
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: MaybeT-0.1.2 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of MaybeT-0.1.2)
rejecting: base-4.10.1.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: MaybeT => base<4.8)
rejecting: base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0,
base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1,
base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0,
base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2,
base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2,
base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed
instance)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, MaybeT
```

I guess this is a common newbie gripe, but I have no idea how to go about fixing this, as Google has told me that trying to upgrade `base` is a very bad idea.  How does this work?

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on these matters, but AFACT, most people (myself included) have left Cabal in favour of [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org). In general, you may have more luck with that.

Comment: If you're trying to install [this particular MaybeT package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MaybeT), the reason it's giving you trouble *could be* that it's fallen behind. While it looks like the last update was in 2015, the original package is from 2007. This could explain the dependency trouble you're seeing. If you need a `Maybe` monad transformer, could you instead use the one 'included' in GHC: [Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html)?

Comment: Though the question I suggested involves Stack, while you are using cabal-install, the issue is the same: as @MarkSeemann points out, if you are using a sufficiently recent GHC the *MaybeT* package is unnecessary, as you can just use the one from *transformers* (`Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe`).